# Bertrand and Mersenne

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am thinking about Bertrand´s postulate. The usual wording “there must be at least one prime between $n$ and $2n-2$” does not exclude a potential for additional squeezing or shortening of this interval. If there is no such possibility (for squeezing), I assume that by necessity the outer limit is  sometimes reached, i.e. for a certain $n$, $n-3$ is a prime, with no other primes in the sequence.
I consider next a starting number $n= 2^k+1$. The first number in the sequence is then $n= 2^k+2$ and the last number is $2n-2= 2^{k+1}$, obviously not a prime. The highest candidate is therefore a Mersenne number, $2^{k+1}-1$.

If the number in the sequence cannot be shortened for any type of sequence, there must for any $n= 2^k+1$ always be some cases where $2^{k+1}-1$ is a prime.
The question is therefore, does Bertrand´s postulate hold for all sequences, or are there some sequences where it doesn´t hold?

If it holds for my special - but infinite number of - sequences it seems to constitute a proof that there are an infinite number of Mersenne primes.

Comment: probably you know this but just in case, the Andrica conjecture states that the gap $g_p$ of prime p up to the next prime, is less than two times the square root of p plus one. $g_n \lt 2\sqrt{p}+1$ but is just an 'empirical' conjecture, while Bertrand is already proved. (if you consider this an answer I will add it to an answer) http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The usual wording “there must be at least one prime between n and 2n-2” does not exclude a potential for additional squeezing or shortening of this interval.

Indeed. In fact it can be improved a lot. For example:

> For every $\epsilon>0$ the exists a $C_{\epsilon}$ such that there is a prime between $n$ and $(1+\epsilon)n$ for every $n \ge C_{\epsilon}$.

Even this is still quite a weak result. For more information, search for information on [prime gaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap).

Comment: In an answer to a  post ”Bertand and Mersenne” a user be the name of “quid” mentioned that for every $ϵ>0$ there exists a Cϵ such that there is a prime between n and (1+ϵ)n for every $n≥Cϵ$. 
The conjecture seems related to this.

Comment: Sorry I do not get the comment. Did you mean to post this elsewhere?

Comment: I conjecture that in a consecutive sequence of nn natural numbers all greater than nn, there exists at least one number which is not divisible by any prime number less than or equal to n/2n/2.

Can any one prove or disprove this?

Comment: sorry again - I am not good with the tools here  - it was about this conjecture by "some one": "I conjecture that in a consecutive sequence of nn natural numbers all greater than nn, there exists at least one number which is not divisible by any prime number less than or equal to n/2n/2. Can any one prove or disprove this?" It may not be relevant.

Comment: I see. I do not know an answer right now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It has been proven that, assuming the Riemann Hypothesis, there is for sufficiently large $n$ always a prime between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$.

Comment: This does not seem quite right in the sense  that assuming RH this is basically trivial, and moreover it is known without assuming RH (it follows e.g. from the  Baker, Harman and Pintz result mentioned on the page I link to).